# How to cancel build process in VisualStudio for a long running custom build tool?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, build, msbuild

I have a custom build step. In this step I have a large long running tool to convert a database into a special static compressed format. This tool handles nearly 2GB of data and runs up 30 minutes.

The tools handles Ctrl+C and Ctrl+Break. And can easily stopped when running from the command line.

But inside VisualStudio (I use currently VS2015) I can't stop this tool to run. The compiler and linker stops when I choose `Build -> Cancel`. But my tool continues to run.

It seams that VS doesn't handle the break signal to the processes it starts.

Is there any trick or setting to abort tools in the build process, without using the task manager?

Comment: It looks like this behaviour is "[by design](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/details/780267)". Possible workaround if you control the source of the tool: add a parameter "/cancel", which sets an event and immediately returns. In the conversion routine periodically check if the event is set and if so, exit program gracefully. In VS, add external tool to the "Extras" menu to call your tool with parameter "/cancel". You'd have to manually invoke this menu item, but still better than using task manager.

Comment: I just found this [Visual Studio extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DenisKuzminreg.vsSolutionBuildEvent-11615) which allows you to run a tool or script on the "Cancel-Build" event. From that you could call your tool with "/cancel" parameter as I outlined in my previous comment.

Comment: I filed a bug with CMake: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/25183

Answer (score 2):

The compiler and linker "know" to stop when you cancel the build because they run as MSBuild [Tool Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.utilities.tooltask), and are sensitive to [ToolCanceled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.utilities.tooltask.toolcanceled) event.
While you cannot do the same thing with custom build step, you can wrap your tool with a class that extends [ToolTask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.utilities.tooltask) and kill your tool when [ToolCanceled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.utilities.tooltask.toolcanceled) event is triggered.

To do that you will need to [register a task](https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/visualstudio/msbuild/task-writing) in your msbuild project file. This is also possible with [inline tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-inline-tasks) with `<Code Type="class" ...`

[ToolTask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.utilities.tooltask) also implements [ICancelableTask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.framework.icancelabletask) so you can override `Cancel()` method in your class and stop your tool when it is called.
`Cancel()` method will be called by MSBuild when the build is cancelled.

Here is an example of an [inline task](https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-inline-tasks) that implements `Cancel()`:

```
 <UsingTask TaskName="MyTool" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll">

    <ParameterGroup> 
      <!-- Tool parameters -->     
    </ParameterGroup>

    <Task>
      <Code Type="Class" Language="cs">
        <![CDATA[  

      using Microsoft.Build.Utilities;
      using Microsoft.Build.Framework;
      using System;

      public class MyTool : Task, ICancelableTask
      {
         public override bool Execute()
         {
           Log.LogMessage(MessageImportance.High, "MyTool: Build started!");

           // Code to run your tool...
         }

         public void Cancel()
         {         
           Log.LogMessage(MessageImportance.High, "MyTool: Build cancelled!");

           // Code to stop your tool...          
         }
      }

       ]]>
      </Code>
    </Task>
  </UsingTask>
```

Comment: It seems you can also use *Task*, not only *ToolTask*. Also, thanks.