# Pass CTRL+C to Cmake custom command under VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake, terminal, signals

I have a Cmake custom target that runs a command-line tool which has to be stopped using CTRL+C. If I run the tool from the terminal, it stops on CTRL+C just fine, but if I build my custom Cmake target, it's impossible to terminate it. I tried to add the `USES_TERMINAL` option to the Cmake target, but that doesn't change anything. Is there a Cmake or VSCode option that I have missed which would allow me to send SIGINT to a Cmake command?

Here's a small project to reproduce the situation:

CMakeLists.txt:

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2.0)
project(test_prj LANGUAGES CXX C)
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON CACHE BOOL "ON")
add_executable(test_prj main.c)
add_custom_target(test_run COMMAND test_prj USES_TERMINAL)
```

main.c:

```c
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char flag = 1;
void sig_handler(int signum) {
    flag = 0;
}


int main(void) {
    signal(SIGINT, sig_handler);
    while(flag);
    printf("success\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Once `test_prj` is compiled, running it in the terminal

```
PS C:\22_Test\build> ./test_prj.exe
<I hit CTRL-C here>
success
```

However, building `test_run` results in the following output:

```
[main] Building folder: 22_Test test_run
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: C:\tools\cmake\3.20.2\bin\cmake.EXE --build c:/22_Test/build --config Debug --target test_run --
[build] [1/3  33% :: 0.108] Building C object CMakeFiles/test_prj.dir/main.c.obj
[build] [2/3  66% :: 0.345] Linking C executable test_prj.exe
[build] [3/3  66% :: 0.345] cmd.exe /C "cd /D C:\22_Test\build && C:\22_Test\build\test_prj.exe"
<I hit CTRL-C here, nothing happens>
```

Comment: Similar question, but about Visual Studio: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43364914/how-to-cancel-build-process-in-visualstudio-for-a-long-running-custom-build-tool

Comment: @ConnorClark Thanks, that indeed looks like a possible solution. I'm not going to do this though, as I don't use .NET and my users would prefer launching my SW in a separate terminal than having .NET as a dependency.